# Alexa always generating intentrequest, never launch request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My intent schema looks like this:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "GetAddressIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.StopIntent"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.CancelIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

The only utterance that maps to the getaddressintent is "GetAddressIntent give me my address"

When I say "Alexa ask " in the service simulator, it should generate a LaunchRequest according to the docs, but this NEVER happens. It always generates a GetAddressIntent. Moreover, no matter what I enter in the service simulator, it is constantly a GetAddressIntent.

I entered "asdfjasdfjalsdfjal;skdfj" in the service simulator and it generated the following request (some details omitted):

```
{
  "session": {
    "new": true,
    "sessionId": "SessionId.19876680-dd64-4420-b51c-209aac45e0ed",
    "application": {
      "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.1cfe092b-45d9-4b76-b9a7-d3c0193e9e32"
    },
    "attributes": {},
    "user": {
      "userId": ".."
    }
  },
  "request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "...",
    "intent": {
      "name": "GetAddressIntent",
      "slots": {}
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "timestamp": "2017-09-07T18:21:45Z"
  },
  "context": {
    "AudioPlayer": {
      "playerActivity": "IDLE"
    },
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": ".."
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "..."
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

Handler:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """ Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
    etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
    """
    print("EVENT: {0}".format(event))
    print("event.session.application.applicationId=" +
          event['session']['application']['applicationId'])

    """
    Uncomment this if statement and populate with your skill's application ID to
    prevent someone else from configuring a skill that sends requests to this
    function.
    """
    ddid = "" #event['context']['System']['device']['deviceId']
    consent_token = "" #event['context']["System"]["user"]["permissions"]["consentToken"]
    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']}, event['session'])
    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'], ddid, consent_token)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_session_ended(event['request'], event['session'])
```

Comment: Did you add "LaunchRequest" check in your handler function?

Comment: Yes let me add my handler

Comment: ok. Please share handler function too.

Comment: Ok I did.......

Comment: Just for debugging it can you please comment the line 'if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']}, event['session'])' and see how it's behaving.

Comment: It still generates an IntentRequest. I tested it by copying the JSON from the Service sim and changing the intent type and it worked fine. I think the service simulator is always generating intent requests no matter what you put in

Comment: hmm simulator some times behave wierd. Did you try it in echo?

Comment: Agreed with @VijayanathViswanathan, the service simulator is not always consistent with real world usage. You will always get a LaunchRequest on the device if you ask "Alexa, open XXX". You can also try echosim.io